# Retain events for dynamically changing elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

### The goal

A good and definitively way to recall functions after something happened.

### The problem

I'm working with some functions that must to be recalled when something happens. A simple example is a button like Twitter's following button.

Until here, all good. But, I do not know how to recall. Actually, I've already tried to use `$.getScript` of jQuery, but it causes many requests to the server and I do not feel comfortable with this behavior.

To illustrate the problem, I made [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2KUp8/1/). When you hover the button for the first time, its style changes. When you click on it and click again, the "hover behavior" disappears.

I really do not know how to proceed.

`$.getScript` it is the best solution for this?

Someone have any suggestion?

### The code (if jsFiddle down)

*The Knockout on the code is just an example and it is irrelevant. I want to do this with ajax calls and everything what is possible.*

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- ko if: isAdded -->
    <button class="btn primary" data-bind="click: add">Add Xbox 360</button>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko ifnot: isAdded -->
    <button class="btn btn-success primary remove" data-bind="click: remove">Xbox 360 already added</button>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("button.remove").hover(function() {
    $(this)
    .removeClass("btn-success")
    .addClass("btn-danger")
    .text("Click here to remove");
}, function() {
    $(this)
    .removeClass("btn-danger")
    .addClass("btn-success")
    .text("Xbox 360 already added");
});

ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.isAdded = ko.observable(false);

    self.add = function(item) {
        item.isAdded(false);
    };

    self.remove = function(item) {
        item.isAdded(true);
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: recalled? You mean run/executed again? How does getScript get involved? It is not even in the fiddle

Comment: I really don't see what the problem is here.

Comment: This is about event handlers. Not sure what `$.getScript` is supposed to have to do with this.

Comment: I would either use event delegation, or a function that i can call when i need to bind the hover event to it again. or maybe even bind the hover effect on state change from add to it's been added

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 5):

You are going to need to use delegated events, which will stay bound as you add/remove/modify elements on the page. See the documenation for jQuery's [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function for more information about event delegation.

Note that this means you will need to use the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events instead of the `hover()` convenience method (which is just a wrapper for attaching listeners for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`)

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', "button.remove", function() {
    $(this)
    .removeClass("btn-success")
    .addClass("btn-danger")
    .text("Click here to remove");
}).on('mouseleave', 'button.remove', function() {
    $(this)
    .removeClass("btn-danger")
    .addClass("btn-success")
    .text("Xbox 360 already added");
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2KUp8/8)**

Answer (score 2):

You need to use event delegation so the handler is bound for current *and future* elements:

```
$('.container').on('mouseenter', 'button.remove', function() {
    ...
}).on('mouseleave', 'button.remove', function() {
    ...
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2KUp8/5/

Read more about event delegation [here](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on` method for dynamically added elements

```
$(document).on("mouseover", "button.remove", function(e) {
    $(this)
    .removeClass("btn-success")
    .addClass("btn-danger")
    .text("Click here to remove");
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", "button.remove", function(e) {
    $(this)
    .removeClass("btn-danger")
    .addClass("btn-success")
    .text("Xbox 360 already added");
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2KUp8/7/)